# Pyramid uWSGI deploy and not iterable 'Router'

Tags: python, pyramid, uwsgi

Hey I have problem with deploying my app with uWSGI:

frontend.ini

```
[uwsgi]
http = *.*.*.*:8181
master = true

#uid = uwsgiuser
#gid = uwsgiuser

processes = 1

harakiri = 60
harakiri-verbose = true
limit-post = 65536
post-buffering = 8192

listen = 128

max-requests = 1000

reload-on-as = 128
reload-on-rss = 96
no-orphans = true

log-slow = true
plugins = python
module = skysoccer.app:main
wsgi-file = /wsgi.py

pythonpath = /eggs/*.egg
pythonpath = /*
pythonpath = *
pythonpath = skysoccer/*
stats= *.*.*.*:8080
```

This is what I get:
http://pastebin.com/KBhMnFv7

And then when I type in webbrowser: http://*.*.*.*:8181/

In cli I get:

```
TypeError: 'Router' object is not iterable
[pid: 13692|app: 0|req: 1/1] *.*.*.* () {36 vars in 630 bytes} [Wed Jul 10 14:36:31 2013] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 737 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

In code I don't have varable "Router".

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not need the `module` option, but rather just a `wsgi.py` file that exposes your wsgi app as the `application` variable.

To do this, a typical `wsgi.py` file might look like:

```
import os.path

from pyramid.paster import get_app
from pyramid.paster import setup_logging

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
inipath = os.path.join(here, 'production.ini')

setup_logging(inipath)
application = get_app(inipath)
```

This would configure your app to load the `production.ini` file that is in the same folder as the `wsgi.py` file.